# Create floor tiles with Python in Maya

Tags: python, arrays, maya, cubes

i want to create floor tiles of different sizes with cubes, but i don't know how to do that.

what i have right now is this: it creates cubes with random size.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random 

cubeList = cmds.ls( 'myCube*' )
if len(cubeList) > 0:
    cmds.delete( cubeList )


for i in range(0,5):

    dRand = random.uniform(0.8,3)

    tegel = cmds.polyCube( name= 'myCube#', w = 1, h=0.8, d = dRand) 
    cmds.move(i, 0, 0)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Random is a good place to start - but you need to give us some more context on what the final result will look like. Sizing and positioning the cubes isn't the tough part: knowing where you  want them is. Do you need to control the distribution in some way? How regular should it be?

Comment: i will make a button to create the tiles. When the user select a plane he/ she can fill the selected plane with tiles, and then the problem will be that some of the cubes will be bigger and out of the plane and i must somehow cut the extra parts to fit it with plane. Now i tried something else, i have the script to align the cubes to the same position of the selected plane

Comment: could you post a picture or something describing the desired results?

Comment: [link] (https://www.google.be/search?q=tiles&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt4ejlt7LRAhVJNhoKHW9iCwUQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=tegels&imgrc=34UdEOCl-E7bfM%3A) i cant put image here, i don't know why. but here is link to a picture. i want to have a result like this

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mrfhixalfgz3vy/Maya_python_FloorTileGenerator.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The result you are trying to achieve is quite complex. Try to start from simple pieces. For example, the complex tiling you showed can be solved starting from filling a plane with big squares. Done that, you can try to define a way to subdivide each square into little squares. And at that point you can start giving random sizes to each square. The real issue is that you need to figure out how to place all the pieces with no overlap. Keep in mind that the sum of the area of each little square should give you the area of the biggest square